# error while get very large amount of documents in one collection in FireStore - asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-cloud-firestore, limit

i try to get about hundred of thousands data from FireStore, but i encounter this kinds of error.
am i reach the limmit of read documents in 1 execution ?

here's the error statement

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="The datastore operation timed out, or the data was temporarily unavailable.", DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException: {"created":"@1648103323.710000000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:34.101.5.42:443","file":"..\..\..\src\core\lib\surface\call.cc","file_line":1067,"grpc_message":"The datastore operation timed out, or the data was temporarily unavailable.","grpc_status":14}")
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.ClientResponseStream`2.MoveNext(CancellationToken token)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.AsyncResponseStream`1.MoveNextAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.<ForEachAsync>g__Core|295_0[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 source, Action`1 action, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Linq.Async\System\Linq\Operators\ForEach.cs:line 31
   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.<ForEachAsync>g__Core|295_0[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 source, Action`1 action, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Linq.Async\System\Linq\Operators\ForEach.cs:line 31
   at Google.Cloud.Firestore.Query.GetSnapshotAsync(ByteString transactionId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at vgr_data.Services.PesertaService.GetWithFilterFaskesExternalAsync(PesertaFilter filter) in D:\Projects\VGR-Data-API\vgr-data\vgr-data\Services\PesertaService.cs:line 994
   at vgr_data.Controllers.PesertaController.ExportFaskesExternal(PesertaFilter filter) in D:\Projects\VGR-Data-API\vgr-data\vgr-data\Controllers\PesertaController.cs:line 2980
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

i tried to get this data with chunk the amount of OFFSET [[ query.OFFSET().GetsnapshotAsync() ]], at first it worked, but since the data is still growing, but now it comes to an error.

```
 int pageCount = 0;
            int dataCount = 1;
            List<MyModel> listItem = new List<MyModel>();

       
            while (dataCount > 0)
            {
                dataCount = 0;

                QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await _query.Offset(40000 * pageCount).Limit(40000).GetSnapshotAsync();
                dataCount = querySnapshot.Count();

                foreach (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot in querySnapshot.Documents)
                {
                    if (documentSnapshot.Exists)
                    {
                        Dictionary<string, object> obj = documentSnapshot.ToDictionary();

                        MyModel item = _mapper.Map<MyModel>(obj);
                        item.Id = documentSnapshot.Id;

                        listItem.Add(item);
                    }
                }
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Total List : "+ listItem.Count());
                pageCount += 1;
            }
```

but at the end, i still get the error after reaching about 400k of data

Answer (score 0):

Firestore [query pagination is based on query cursors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) is based on query cursors, and the documentation [recommends against using offsets](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#read_and_write_operations):

> Do not use offsets. Instead, use cursors. Using an offset only avoids returning the skipped documents to your application, but these documents are still retrieved internally. The skipped documents affect the latency of the query, and your application is billed for the read operations required to retrieve them.

It looks like your read operation is timing out on the Firestore side, and I suspect this `offset` call may be involved:

```
_query.Offset(40000 * pageCount).Limit(40000)
```

I recommend rewriting your code to use cursor-based queries for pagination.